# The logon attempt failed error while connecting Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

I need to connect to a Windows 8.1 Professional (A) version using MS Remote Desktop.

Accessing the machine using RDP on Windows 7 I can access the machine with no problems (B).
Accessing the machine using RDP on a Windows 8.1 Home machine I get the following errors (C):

```
The logon attempt failed error while connecting Remote Desktop
```

On both machines (B / C / A), antivirus and firewalls are disabled.

It seems a problem related to (C).

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you ping A from C? Can you access A's shared folders/files from C?

Comment: @Dave I can ping A from C.

Comment: And what about the shared folders? Are you RDP'ing via IP or computer name?

Comment: I do not see the shared folders

Comment: have you enabled remote access on C?

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: It's really a puzzle... Can it be the username format? Have you tried ".\username" or "username@Workgroup_C"?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue adding the computer name before the user name using RDP on Win 8, when instead on Win 7 would works only with the username, example below. I hope it could help others.

```
On Windows 8.1

ip:
123.123.123
user:
MYPC\myuser
password:
mypasword

On Windows 7
ip:
123.123.123
user:
myuser
password:
mypasword
```

Comment: You genius, I wasted so much time, trying to play with firewalls and group policies etc. Simple `PcName\Username` worked like a charm